# How to pull a pin low?

Tags: motor, stepper

On the instructions for [this motor driver](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/easy-driver-hook-up-guide), it says that motors can be put to sleep by "pulling a pin low".

> **SLP** - Logic Input. When pulled LOW, outputs are disabled and power consumption is minimized.

I'm guess this means connect to ground? How could I trigger that via my Arduino board?

Answer (score 3):

Connect it to an IO port and set it to OUTPUT and LOW. That's what it means to "pull low".

It helps if you understand how an IO port works. [This may help you.](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/20/what-exactly-is-a-gpio-pin/)

Comment: Thanks – I get that this makes the Arduino pin go low, but will it also "pull" the pin on the driver to ground?

Comment: Yes, that is what going LOW is. Did you read the tutorial I linked to?

Comment: Sometimes it also is needed to put a resistor from the pin to ground to pull it low, or put a resistor to +5V to pull it high. This happens in cases where a pin needs to be set before the sketch can set a pin to low or high.